# orchardcms/mvc null values when posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public class Address
    {
        public string Street { get; set;}
    }


public class MyModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set;}
        public Address MyAddress { get; set;}
    }


public class MyController : Controller
{
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DoStuff(MyModel model)
        {
            // model.Name has its value
            // model.MyAddress is there, but its .Street is always null
            // Do stuff
        }
}
```

This is how i post to the controller

```
var data =
    {
        __RequestVerificationToken: $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val(),
        Name: "Arnold",
        MyAddress: 
        {
               Street: "my address"
        }
    }

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/myroute/dostuff", //Yes i should not use the hardcoded url but this is just for show
        data: data,
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            // ...
        },
        dataType: 'json',
    });
```

Looking at fiddler its posting the correct data..
If i look at the ModelState its only got one Key, "Name".

**EDIT:**

If i do this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DoStuff(FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            // formCollection has all the data..
            // so i guess its the binding? :o any ideas how to fix?
            // Do stuff
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this should be tagged OrchardCms: it seems to be purely an ASP.NET MVC model binding problem.
Also missing from the question: the structure of the post. Model binding largely relies on conventions on how the post data is structured.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you call `UpdateModel(model)` on the first line of the action method? It could be because model binding hasn't picked up the Address property implicitly and you need to give it an explicit nudge.

Comment: If i do UpdateModel(model) i get an System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.", InnerException: "Collection is read-only".

Comment: That's odd. Your `MyModel` object doesn't have any collection properties. Anything else useful in the stack trace?

Comment: Ah yea, ur right, i was looking at the wrong piece of code :P

However, Doing UpdateModel(model) does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: How about `UpdateModel(model.MyAddress)`?

Comment: What gets passed across in the `FormCollection`? It could be related to how the form elements are named before the form is posted back. Model binding only works if the form has the correctly named elements to bind from.

Comment: The key in the FormCollection looks like "MyAddress[Street]"